# Most Active Contributors Quarterly Report! - 2nd Quarter 2017

Tags: discussion, most-active-contributors, quarterly

## Welcome Our SharePoint Stack Exchange Valued Contributors.

We would like to share the **Most Active Contributors Report** over the Second Quarter 2017!

[image]

**This report includes the following awards:**

1. Quarterly Leader Board.
2. Most Active Contributors Award.
3. Most Active Editors Award.
4. Most Active Voters Award.
5. 1st Top Contributors summary list.

---

[image]

[image]

You can find the full list at [Stack Exchange Leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/105/quarter/sharepoint/2017-04-01)

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                   REPUTATION
----------------------------------------------------------
1   M.Qassas                  4,551
2   Venkat Konjeti            3,264
3   Waqas Sarwar MVP          2,305
4   Gautam Sheth              2,263
5   Danny '365CSI' Engelman   2,006
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                    EDITS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   M.Qassas                   453
2   SynozeN IT Solutions       358
3   Suresh Bolineni            143
4   TARUN                      126
5   Robert Lindgren            113
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                     VOTES
----------------------------------------------------------
1   Michelle                   1126
2   ViperOrton                 684
3   Aashirya                   636
4   M.Qassas                   507
5   Danny '365CSI' Engelman    501
```

---

[image]

1. **Most Active Contributors Award.**

   - [M.Qassas](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/m-qassas) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
2. **Most Active Voters Award.**

   - [Michelle](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/34941/michelle) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
3. **Most Active Editors Award.**

   - [M.Qassas](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/m-qassas) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!

---

Please join me in thanking all contributors for volunteering, We fully appreciate all the great contributions of SE members. Please keep your valuable contributing!

> **P.S.:** This report will be published Monthly (12 awards) / Quarterly (3 awards) / Yearly (3 awards) based on the available data. Please don't hesitate to share your valuable feedback & precious suggestion!

Comment: Congratulations all for your persistent efforts to make the community successful.

Comment: Congratulations @m.qassas for your extraordinary work you do in this community. You deserve the gold prize of SE.

Comment: Good job guys, I use this site everyday I hope to see activity grow even more